# How to do swap using encoded function call

Tags: solidity, 0x

I will try to describe my problem as clearly as possible so that I can get feedback on whether I am going in the right direction for resolution.

I'm running tests on mainnet fork trying to implement a vault on top of Zapper. They have implemented an easy way to interact with many of protocols where I can "swap" a Token for a LP Token or another yield-bearing-token. The problem is that they are not answering how to use they API in contexts that they don't documented.

Taking as example [that transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb2f92815fd71ea6d133361772c9c317182489d7cc3bcb85e2fbee9d7134e28be) where the user bought a proportional investment in a pool with the token LOOK and WETH starting with his USDC.

Looking at [their contract code](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc695f73c1862e050059367b2e64489e66c525983#code) you can see that everything is done through the function `ZapIn` (the function that I'm trying to use) and this function require some parameters pretty self explanatory but one specific called swapData in a bytes format. I realized the data passed in this field will just be used in the step: `_swapTarget.call.value(valueToSend)(swapCallData);` and until there I did'n know about it but studying I discovered that is encoded function call where the `bytes hash` encodes the name and parameters of the function.

Now, I have some questions. Inspecting the transaction we can see that their are using 0x to perform the swaps and I read their documentations trying to find how can I build this swapData field and use the ZapIn function but I'm blocked.

The guys on 0x discord said that 0x doesn't perform multi-swap of tokens but you can see on this transaction that Zapper are swapping USDC for WTH and then for LOOKS and their code just call the 0x once.[image]

To summarize my question is:

How can I build this bytes sequence to pass through the ZapIn function and call the 0x to swap the tokens?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your transaction and : click to see more .

Where you can debug and see what raw bytes was passed to the function .

remeber that the first 4 bytes is used to call the function ZapIn() and the rest are arguments passed .

You can decode it .
[image]

Comment: I already decoded and saw the parameters but the swapData I couldn't decode without the encode signature/schema.